# Best way to write function for SQL SERVER 2014

Tags: php, sql-server

I am learning to write an function to fetch the user_status from SQL server.I generally use mysqli database and in the PHP i write code as :

```
function fetchuserStatus($username,$password){
  global $mysqli;
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT user_status from table_name where username = ? AND password = ?");
  $stmt->bind_param("ss",$username,$password);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($userstatus);
  $stmt->store_result();
  $stmt->fetch();
  $stmt->close();
  return $userstatus;
}
```

Now i want to write same for the SQL SERVER. How can i do that? As i did connection with SQL SERVER what would be the best way to write code for sql server.

NOTE: I am using PHP 7.1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry but the mysqli extension is MySQL-only (as its name suggestes)—it simply cannot speak the protocol of any other database engine. (Because you are not asking about the [`CREATE FUNCTION` statement in Transact-SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755%28v=sql.120%29.aspx), are you?)

Comment: I already got Ans what i am exactly looking for. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out PHP sql server documentation http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php

But if we were to translate that to sql server.

```
function fetchuserStatus($username,$password){
  $conn = sqlsrv_connect('localhost', array("Database"=>"USERS_TBL", "UID"=>"dbuser", "PWD"=>"dbpassword");
  if ($conn) {
      $sql = "SELECT user_status from table_name where username = ? AND password = ?");
      $parameters = array($username,$password);
      $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $parameters);
      if(sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt) === true) {
          sqlsrv_fetch($stmt);
          /*
           Use results however you want
           You can get results using sqlsrv_get_field($stmt, 0);
           0 is the index of the column on your select, if you selected something after user_status then that column would be 1 
          */
      }
      sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
      sqlsrv_close($conn);
  }
}
```

Comment: is it necessary to write again use sqlsvr_connect. Can't we just directly include the file.

Comment: @NikitaAgrawal I just added that so you can see how to connect to the server. But yeah, if you want to add that to a separate file, you can.

Comment: if i am not using $conn its showing $conn: Undefined variable

Comment: Is this function support  PHP Version 7.1.12. Because after editing everything I am not getting any output. Now i think its should get output

Comment: Yes it's supported, make sure you install everything right and check your server if sqlsrv is enabled, SEE http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.installation.php AND https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver

Comment: Yes i am getting if($conn) echo "Connection establised";  I am getting here connection established.